# Field missing in Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my model:

```
class SystemConfiguration(models.Model):
  idSystemConfiguration = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  mail_movement_subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Movement Triggered")
  mail_snapped_subject  = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Image Snapped")
  mail_carbon_subject   = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Carbon Monoxide Triggered")
  mail_door_subject     = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Door Activity Triggered")
  door1_name            = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Garage Door")
  door2_name            = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Garage Door 2")
  door3_name            = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Garage Door 3")
  metric                = models.BooleanField()
  mail_temp_subject     = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Temperature Triggered")
  min_temp              = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=4)
  max_temp              = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=4)
  mail_humidity_subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Humidity Triggered")
  mail_to_user          = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
  min_humidity          = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=3)
  max_humidity          = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1,max_digits=3)

  def setDefaults(self):
    print "Creating SystemConfig..."
    self.mail_movement_subject = "Movement Triggered"
    self.mail_snapped_subject  = "Image Snapped"
    self.mail_carbon_subject   = "Carbon Monoxide Triggered"
    self.mail_door_subject     = "Door Activity Triggered"
    self.door1_name            = "Garage Door"
    self.door2_name            = "Garage Door 2"
    self.door3_name            = "Garage Door 3"
    self.metric                = False
    self.mail_temp_subject     = "Temperature Triggered"
    self.min_temp              = 28
    self.max_temp              = 100
    self.mail_humidity_subject = "Humidity Triggered"
    self.min_humidity          = 40
    self.max_humidity          = 50
    self.mail_to_user          = ""
    self.save()

  def __str__(self):
    return "SystemConfiguration:" + str(self.idSystemConfiguration) \
      + ",mail_movement_subject:" + str(self.mail_movement_subject) \
      + ",mail_snapped_subject:" + str(self.mail_snapped_subject) \
      + ",mail_carbon_subject:" + str(self.mail_carbon_subject) \
      + ",mail_door_subject:" + str(self.mail_door_subject) \
      + ",Door1Name:" + str(self.door1_name) \
      + ",Door2Name:" + str(self.door2_name) \
      + ",Door3Name:" + str(self.door3_name) \
      + ",Metric:" + str(self.metric) \
      + ",mail_temp_subject:" + str(self.mail_temp_subject) \
      + ",minTemp:" + str(self.min_temp) \
      + ",maxTemp:" + str(self.max_temp) \
      + ",mail_humidity_subject:" + str(self.mail_humidity_subject) \
      + ",minHumid:" + str(self.min_humidity) \
      + ",maxHumid:" + str(self.max_humidity) \
      + ",mail_to_user:" + str(self.mail_to_user) \
      + ",wan_port:" + str(self.wan_port) \
      + ",wan_video_port:" + str(self.wan_video_port) \
      + "\n"
```

Here is where I am trying to access it (note that I am running a script outside of django, and hence the sys.path.apend(...) and os.environ[...] shenanigans:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/garageMonitor"))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'garageMonitor.settings'
from garageMonitor.models import SystemConfiguration

def handleMailFile(file):
    config = SystemConfiguration.objects.filter(idSystemConfiguration=1)
    config = config[0]
    for x in config.__dict__:
      print x
    print len(config.__dict__)
```

Here is the results of the run:

```
mail_snapped_subject
mail_humidity_subject
mail_carbon_subject
max_humidity 
door2_name 
max_temp
_state 
idSystemConfiguration
min_humidity 
mail_door_subject 
min_temp 
door3_name 
mail_temp_subject 
mail_movement_subject 
metric 
door1_name 
16
```

Note that **all** of the fields **except** mail_to_user are printed in the for loop!  I checked the database and sure enough, the mail_to_user field is there with the correct length and type.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

I tried adding another field identical to one that was actually working (changed the name.) Django created the field in the database, but it did not show up in the list of **dict** elements either?!?

I added another column in the database with django code and re-ran the setup.  The coded added the column (with the default value), but still when I run the following:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/garageMonitor"))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'garageMonitor.settings'
from garageMonitor.models import SystemConfiguration
config = SystemConfiguration.objects.filter(idSystemConfiguration=1)
config = config[0]
for x in config.__dict__:
  print x

print len(config.__dict__)
```

I only get 16 entries in the **dict** object and the new column is not there.  I removed all .pyc files thinking there may be some artifact laying around, but that did not help either.

So, I tried another approach.  I created a new model (Jordan) by copying the original one and added it to the models.py file.  I ran the setup code.  It created the table correctly in the database, but when I tried to access the model, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Jordan
```

Arrrgggghhhhh!!!!!

tried moving to another directory (django) and ran the following:

```
python...
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'garageMonitor.settings'
from garageMonitor.models import Jordan
config = Jordan.objects.filter(idSystemConfiguration=1)
config = config[0]
for x in config.__dict__:
  print x
```

And here is my output:

```
_known_related_objects
_sticky_filter
_db
_result_cache
_prefetch_done
_for_write
query
model
_prefetch_related_lookups
_hints
```

(not remotely like what the database table looks like!)

Comment: what value does the `mail_to_user` field have? You can check by performing the query in the python shell (e.g. `./manage shell`) or via a db-browser (e.g. phpmyadmin or phppgadmin). If it's empty, as the value set by default, you aren't going to see anyhting

Comment: I would think that if the field was empty, the value would be empty.  Anyway, the field has data in it.

Comment: I am sorry, I am sleeping almost. You are iterating on the `__dict__` dictionary. That allows you to print its keys, which are the names of the instance attributes, not their value. In case you want to print both their name and value you need to iterate on `config.__dict__.items()`

Comment: As I mentioned before, mail_to_user is **not** printed out in the list of keys, so adding printout for its value would be pointless.